# How do I get the nth element of a Seq?

Tags: scala

I want to get the nth element of a `Seq`, something like this:

```
val mySeq = Seq("A", "B", "C")
mySeq.get(1) // Java syntax for List. This does not work.
```

Comment: For future reference, you can find the API docs for `Seq` [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.collection.Seq).

Comment: Ah yes. That's where I ended up finding the answer.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`mySeq.apply(1)` is another way to say `mySeq(1)`

```
scala> val mySeq = Seq("A", "B", "C")
mySeq: Seq[String] = List(A, B, C)

scala> mySeq(0)
res0: String = A

scala> mySeq(1)
res1: String = B
```

Comment: Note that the shorthand `apply` syntax is the same as the syntax usually used to access the *nth* element of an array in Scala. This gives us a nice symmetry between Sequences and Arrays. E.g., `val mySum = mySeq(0) + myArray(0)`

Answer (score 29):

To avoid index out of bounds,

```
scala> mySeq(200)
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 200
  at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.apply(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:65)
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.apply(List.scala:84)
  ... 33 elided
```

lift the sequence,

```
mySeq.lift(2)
Some(C)

mySeq.lift(200)
None
```

or in a similar way,

```
mySeq.drop(2).headOption
Some(C)

mySeq.drop(200).headOption
None
```

By lifting the sequence we define a partial function from `Int` onto each value of the sequence. Namely from each position index onto its corresponding value. Hence positions not defined (any negative value or larger than the size of the collection) are mapped onto `None`, the rest are defined and become `Some` value.

Answer (score 6):

The method to get the *n*th element of a `Seq` is `apply`:

```
val mySeq = Seq("A", "B", "C")
mySeq.apply(1) // "B"
```

Usually, you will never write `x.apply(y)` and just use shorthand `x(y)`. The Scala compiler will convert it for you.

```
mySeq(1) // "B"
```

To avoid potential index out of bounds, you can wrap using `Try`.

```
Try(mySeq(x)).toOption
```

This will return `None` when `x` >= 3 and `Some(...)` when `x` < 3.

Answer (score 0):

Further to Tom's answer, a specific use case where .apply() is necessary, is if you have an object which you just cast to a seq. In that case you cannot use (), since your object is not named. Here is an example:

```
println("Count of column test in MyDF is "+MyDF.groupBy().agg(count("test")).first.toSeq.apply(0));
```

Or, sticking to the example above:

```
println("Second element of Seq(\"A\", \"B\", \"C\") is: "+Seq("A", "B", "C").apply(1));

Second element of Seq("A", "B", "C") is: B
```